# Java - Using Regex to pull substrings out of dataset

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

Given the following dataset, I am trying to find a way to use Regex to pull out city names.

> Boston (MA), New York City (NY, CT, NJ)
>
> New York City (NY, CT, NJ), Philadelphia (PA, NJ)
>
> Indianapolis (IN), St. Louis (MO, IL)
>
> St. Louis (MO, IL), Kansas City (MO, KS)

I want the output of the Regex to be:

> Boston,New York City
>
> New York City,Philadelphia
>
> Indianapolis,St. Louis
>
> St. Louis,Kansas City

I attempted to pattern match based on two criteria:

`(\\w+\\w(?=.())) | (\\w+\\W\\h\\w+(?=.()))`

1. Cities consisting of letters from `[a-zA-Z]+` such as Boston or Philadelphia
2. One-word consisting of additional characters such as periods/additional spaces.

The expression accurately matches the first case. However, for the second case, it only matches the first occurrence of `St. Louis`.

I also tried the following:

`(\\w+ ?\\w(?=.())) | (\\w+\\h\\w+\\h\\w+(?=\\s.()))| (\\w+\\h\\w+(?=\\s.()))`

1. The first covers the same case as listed above - consisting of one-word cities.
2. The third one manages to cover the case of `New York City`, however, just as the first one, fails to recognize cases of the same pattern following that.
3. And the same case as used in the last pattern, which matched `St. Louis` fails to match, and matched `Kansas City` instead.

Comment: should it be `NC,GA`? (no space)

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: Please share your attempts. Also, it would be good to know what programming language/tool you plan to use the regex in.

Answer (score 0):

This can be user for .Net

```
(((?<=\())\w{2})|(\w{2}(?=\)))|(\w{2}(?=,))
```